# jdbc in android, NullPointerException thrown

Tags: android, jdbc

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String id ;
String name ;
int price;

private ResultSet result;
private Connection con;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fyp_restaurant";
String username = "root";
String password = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Cannot create connection");
    }

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM product";
        result = statement.executeQuery(query);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error");
    }

    try {
        id = result.getString("id");
        name = result.getString("name");
        price = result.getInt("price");
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID" + id + "\nName" + name + "\nPrice" + price,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I don't know whether my jar file is in the correct directory - Should it be in `libs`?  I am using android studio. Do I need to add it as library in android studio?

Comment: the error should be in "con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);"

Comment: what type error do you get?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.fyp.fyp/com.company.fyp.fyp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could not create connection to database server. it is the exception message

Answer (score 0):

You connect to the MYSQL server over the network, and the MYSQL server can not be used by root user.
[image]